# NSURLConnection async not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an asynchronous NSURL Request, but I'm getting all "FALSE."

```
-(BOOL)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host{

   BOOL __block isOnline = NO;
   NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:host] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
      if([(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]==200){
         isOnline = TRUE;
      }
   }];
   NSLog(@"%i",isOnline);
   return isOnline;
}
```

Also, this code is being called "6" times when I'm actually just using it with a:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and there are only 3 cells, or 3 items in my data source. First time dealing with async and callbacks in Objective-C, so a detailed answer would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should realize that this problem is *inherently* asynchronous. You *can't* solve it with a *synchronous* approach. That is, your accepted solution is just an elaborated and suboptimal wrapper which ends up being eventually asynchronous anyway.

The better approach is to use an asynchronous method with a completion handler, e.g.:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(BOOL isReachable);

-(void)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

You can implement is as follows (even though the request isn't optimal for checking reachability):

```
-(void)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host 
                   completion:(completion_t)completionHandler 
{
   NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:host]];
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
      if (completionHandler) {
          completionHandler(connectionError == nil && [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]==200);
      }
   }];
}
```

**Please note:**

- Don't set a timeout as short as in your original code.
- The completion handler will be called on a private thread.

**Usage:**

```
[self checkConnectionForHost:self.host completion:^(BOOL isReachable){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.reachableLabel.text = isReachable ? @"" : @"Service unavailable";
    });    
}];
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems faster, but how do I hop back onto the main thread to update my UI? I need to return a connection status.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Updated my answer with a Usage example.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Also, I'm a little new to Obj-C myself, is there a good resource where I can learn about threads, blocks, and just async processes in general? Thanks again!

Comment: You may start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for all the resources. I have one more question though. It seems as though the values are getting mixed up when I call the method through `-collectionView...`. First of all, the method is being called more times than it should be (twice as many method calls as cells). Also, I'm getting "online" for junk URLs like `9009809`. I also tested with `[NSURLConnection canMakeConnection...]`, and it returned "false," so I think there's something wrong with the way it's being called.

Comment: You are likely setting the "cell's value" inappropriately. Due to the asynchronous method and the re-use of cells the re-used cell might be associated to a different cell index *when* the asynchronous method completes than when the call was initiated and thus set's the re-used cell's value instead.

Comment: On the other hand, you will likely face even more issues if you try to test reachability of more than a few hosts (more than 5), since NSURLConnection will limit the actual number of simultaneously connections, and any more connections may timeout prematurely *before* they even started.

Comment: thanks, is there a good way to preserve the cell so that the async return will be associated with it? I would assume that the "queue" takes care of these things

Comment: @Carpetfizz Yes, "capture" the _indexPath_ instead of the cell object, and retrieve the actual cell corresponding to that indexPath within the completion handler. Btw, this is a common issue/problem and asked frequently on SO. You'll find a couple of good answers to this problem ;)

Answer (score 5):

Asynchronous calls will be executed in parallel, and its result will receive in the completion block. In your case, the return statement will be executed before the completion of the Asynchronous request. That will be always FALSE.

You should use Synchronous request for this, and handle not to Block the UI.

```
-(BOOL)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host{

    BOOL isOnline = NO;
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:host] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response status Code : %d",response.statusCode);
    isOnline = response.statusCode == 200;

    return isOnline;    
}
```

You can use that method inside dispatch queues,

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    BOOL status = [self checkConnectionForHost:@"http://google.com"];
    NSLog(@"Host status : %@",status ? @"Online" : @"Offline");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I do the sync request without blocking the UI?

Comment: @Carpetfizz Just want to know, why don't you use [Reachability Class](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) to check Host's Reachability.

Comment: I was referred to `NSURLConnection` from another thread due to Reachability having a lot of bugs

Comment: Thanks for the edit, this is what I had before I realized my UI was updating too slowly. Is there a general concept I should learn so that my UI doesn't slow down while doing this?

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question perfectly, but is there a reason my UI is running much slower because of the async?

Answer (score 1):

Your `isOnline` is probably being set to YES, but it's happening asynchronously. It is almost certainly executing after you log out the value of `isOnline`. So you should move your `NSLog()` call up into the block you pass as the handler to the asynchronous URL request.