# Calling Rest Service from UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, httprequest

I am implementing a UITableView. It's data is pulled from a Web Service in JSON format. But my problem is , there's a field in every custom UITableViewCell for which there's another Rest service. It's kind of, what we usually do in when we load image asynchronously in UITableView.
The field I am talking about is JSON data , not an image.

So, for this reason I'll need to call the rest service from `cellForRowatIndexPath` method , but I know it's a bad idea and I can't download them all before reloading the UITableView.
I know it's kind of weird , but the REST service has been coded like this. So, I have no way other than pulling data for every cell.

In short, I have to call a rest service from every cell of my UITableView to update one field of that corresponding cell.

So, What approaches should be good in this situation ?

Comment: seems [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896308/nsurlconnection-async-not-working/)

Comment: I just need to know the approach , I can change and correct codes myself.

Comment: Hope you can solve that from the related answer?

Comment: My case is a bit complicated, probably some more efficient way would be better . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your case you can use `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation`.

Create an `NSOperation` subclass to perform your `HTTPRequest`.

For every `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` queue up that `NSOperation`, make sure that not to queue same request multiple times. Since cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called repeatedly while you scroll for the same cell, you should take care of queue and keep the status on your data model.

Best NSOperationQueue tutorials are available

[How To Use NSOperations and NSOperationQueues by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

[Working with the NSOperationQueue Class](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsoperationqueue/)

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with a similar approach. Thanks for your help.